# How do I search my Friends' profiles in Facebook

Tags: facebook

Is there any way I can search for words matching anywhere in my Facebook friends' Profiles or Timelines or anything else they have on Facebook?

P.S.: a wordcloud of the most commonly used words in my friends' content would help too.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the graph search.A query like this could help.
If X is your friends name then try these,

```
my friends that work at x
my friends that like x
my friends that live in x-city
my friends that go to x-school
my friends that work at x and live in x-city
my friends that work at x and go to x-school
my friends that work at x and like x
my friends that work at x and visited x
my friends that work at x and visited x-city/state
my friends who work at x
my friends who like x
my friends who live in x-city
my friends who go to x-school
my friends who work at x and live in x-city
my friends who work at x and go to x-school
my friends who work at x and like x
my friends who work at x and visited x
my friends who work at x and visited x-city/state
```

Answer (score -1):

That is not possible. Better try searching with any parts of their name or email address. If you cannot find still, better use the filters wisely.